# Universal turing machine examples

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

I'm looking for a well explained implementation of a universal turing machine, using a binary alphabet. Particularly, I'm looking for an action table for such a UTM with explanations. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find these links of interest:

1. [A page from MIT of a UTM implemented in Scheme](http://web.mit.edu/manoli/turing/www/turing.html)
2. [A contest for the implementation of the shortest UTM](http://www.mathrix.org/experimentalAIT/TuringMachine.html)
3. [A turing machine written in C](http://www2.lns.mit.edu/~dsw/turing/turing.html)
4. [Turing machine written in Haskell](http://code.google.com/p/hs-turing-machine/)
5. [Java implementation of a UTM](https://github.com/thiyagaraj/universal-turing-machine/blob/master/src/TuringMachine.java)

I hope you find these links sufficient to put you in the right direction.